# CanvasContent1 Does not return proper html with its Site page design in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

When we are attempting to use CanvasContent1 to display the content of a SharePoint site page on a SPFx webpart, the page content is not displayed in the same layout, and the styles of the image and page content tables and other controls are not the same as the site page.
How to fix the issue.

[CanvasContent1 HTML render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIo1A.png)

[Site Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmzio.png)

I tried multiple ways to fix this issue.
Retrieved all of the metadata and verified it.
Reviewed the SPFx code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the necessary CSS stylesheets are being applied to the SPFx web part. Make sure that the styles used in the SharePoint site page are also included in the SPFx solution.
You may need to import or include the required CSS files in your SPFx web part code.